# Hadoop Cluster setup in a server or hadoop cluster setup using pcs for performance testing

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing, performance-testing

Which of the following hadoop cluster setup would be best suitable for performance testing?

Setup 1 : Server based cluster

Setup 2 : Common PCs are used as data nodes.

Cluster size is upto 100 Nodes

Also what would be the pros and cons of both cluster setups mentioned above?